# Circular Dependency in MVC std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I am trying to create this MVC structure for my project. I am using shared_ptr and weak_ptr for the first time and getting a lot of issues other than circular dependency too.

Model is Observable. View is Observer.

```
class Observable
{
    std::set< std::shared_ptr<Observer> > observers;
public:
    Observable( void );
    void registerObserver( std::shared_ptr<Observer>  );
    void removeObserver( std::shared_ptr<Observer> & );
    void notifyObservers( void );
    virtual ~Observable( void );
};


class Observer
{
public:
    Observer(void);
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual ~Observer(void);
};

    class Model : public Observable 
{
public:
    Model(void);
    void internalStateChange();
    void funcForController();
    int getSomethingForView() const;
    ~Model(void);
};

class View :
public Observer
{
std::weak_ptr<Model> model;
std::shared_ptr<Controller> controller;
public:
View( const std::shared_ptr<Model> &, const std::shared_ptr<Controller> & );
void update() override;
~View(void);
};

class Controller
{
std::shared_ptr<Model> model;
std::shared_ptr<View> view;
public:
Controller( std::shared_ptr<Model> & );
void changeHappened() const;
~Controller(void);
};
```

My Output is:
[image]

This shows it is hanging up somewhere and then after like 50 seconds it terminates with no other output.
[image]

Controller is not getting destroyed. :(

How do i solve the problem ?

Comment: Considered using [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)?

Comment: I do not understand where should i use it ?. I am using it for model in view.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is well documented in the boost documentation too, so have a look.
I myself wrote a very quick note on the use of weak pointers for breaking reference cycles as an appendix in my master dissertation (find it [here](http://etd.adm.unipi.it/theses/available/etd-04202010-110942/unrestricted/document.pdf)).
Do check the references, since the topic cannot be fully covered in two lines.

The standard library provides the programmer with two diﬀerent classes (in fact, there are other smart pointers too) namely `shared_ptr`
and `weak_ptr`. Shared pointer is a smart pointer keeping a pointer to an object and an additional pointer to a shared reference counter. Every time
a copy of the smart pointer is made the reference count is automatically
increased by 1. When a shared pointer is destroyed (or used in order to reference a diﬀerent object), the reference counter for its object (or the one for
its previous object) is decremented. Shared pointers constructed form raw
pointers initially have a reference count of 1. When the reference counter
reaches 0, the pointed object is automatically destroyed. Weak pointers are
used in order to break loops into the referencing structure. They can be
used to obtain a shared pointer to the same object and check whether the
object has already been destroyed. They do not involve reference counting.
Weak pointers are not intended to be directly dereferenced (i.e. they cannot
be used to gain access to the referenced object, as to do so may lead to
crashes or random behaviour; they can, in fact, be dangling pointerst).

As for your specific problem, the point is this: you have a class

```
class Controller
{
public:
std::shared_ptr<View> view;
};
```

and another class:

```
class View :
public Observer
{
public:
std::shared_ptr<Controller> controller;
};
```

and you "assign" one to each other, i.e.

```
std::shared_ptr<Controller> c(new Controller);
std::shared_ptr<View> v(new View);
c->view = v;
v->controller = c;
```

when `c` and `v` go out of scope the distructors do not get called, since there is still one reference for `c` (`v->controller`) and one for `v` (`c->view`).

The solution, in two words, is to substitute one of the two `shared_ptr`s with a `weak_ptr`. Of course you don't just peek one of the two at random, which one to substitute depends on your design, and you might well end up substituting the both of them (it all depends on ownership semanthics). However, if you substitute (at least) one of them, the issue is solved.

The same applyies to all reference cycles you have in your design